# In FB API one FB user has two different userIDs. Why? How to control it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I observe a weird thing from FB API. One user has two different IDs.

I use FB JavaScript SDK on client.

First, I call `FB.getLoginStatus` request. The response is like this:

```
authResponse: {
    accessToken: "EAAa8S8Ocf.....QZBQ9BPQZDZD",
    expiresIn: 7045,
    grantedScopes: "email,contact_email,public_profile",
    signedRequest: "rFndHA67......M5MDMifQ",
    userID: "x895xxxxxxx3909",  // this is userID #1
}
status: "connected"
```

Then I call `FB.api` for received `userID` and I get completely different user ID:

```
"id": "x304xxxxxxx3177", // different user ID
"name": "John Doe",
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe",
"age_range": {
    "min": 21
},
"link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/x304xxxxxxx3177/",
"gender": "male",
"locale": "en_US",
"timezone": 8,
"updated_time": "2017-02-03T17:34:27+0000",
"verified": true
```

How is it possible? What kind of Easter egg from FB API this is and how to conquer it?

The real user id is the second one, it is in a url for user profile:

> https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=x304xxxxxxx3177

Here is my full request flow:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(status => {
    if(status.status == 'connected') {

        // Here FB sends one userID
        // status.authResponse.userID == x895xxxxxxx3909

        FB.api('/' + status.authResponse.userID, 'get', {fields: '...'},
        response => {

            // And here FB sends different userID for the same user
            // response.id == x304xxxxxxx3177
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Since API v2.0, user ids are app-scoped. But why are you taking the user id out of the auth response data structure in the first place, why don’t you just use `/me`?

Comment: 1) What does it mean *user ids are app-scoped*? How do I distinguish a user when it has two ids?
2) It doesn't matter if I use `/me` or `status.authResponse.userID`, FB still can't return correct user id. It returns user id absolutely unpredictably and arbitrary. One time it returns `status.authResponse.userID`, other time it returns `response.id`

Comment: App-scoped means the id your app sees for the user is specific to your app. Other apps will see a different id. (If you need to be able to identify users across different apps, you need to add them to the same business first.) _“It doesn't matter if I use /me or status.authResponse.userID, FB still can't return correct user id”_ - maybe your assumption that what you got was a _wrong_ id is not true in the first place?

Comment: @Green Did you ever resolve this? I think I am having the same issue and this is the only discussion I have found about it online apart from your github issues.

Comment: @Green did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I'm having similar issues: one of our users logins through javascript sdk, all is well, we get an access token and a user id. User sends those to backend to validate against the graph api and it errors. If I manually put the token in graph api explorer I get an id ending in `5`, whilst js sdk returned an id ending in `6` everything else is the same.

Comment: Haha, well, it seems we did some int casting on the ids... BIG NO NO PEOPLE! (Apparently javascript just subtracts one if it it exceeds `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, who knew... <= a lot of people probably, but I didn't.)

Answer (score 2):

The User ID associated with your application(APP_ID).

Facebook's API provides each application one unique User ID.

Comment: This is the right answer, although I had a WTF moment when I first read it.

Comment: This seems like a facebook bug to me, it is happening with the same APP_ID. Before 7 months a user node had id X, 7 months after the same user node (for same fbemail) had a different id of Y.